# Execute stored procedure with in and out parameter in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with **one In Parameter** and **one Out parameter**. I need to execute the procedure using hibernate JPA. I am not using Spring, only Hibernate.

Tried calling using **@NamedStoredProcedureQuery**, but in this case my *entityManger is throwing null pointer exception*.

while trying with native sql and executed calling query.list(), I am getting an error saying "number of parameter mismatch".

Can anyone help with some example on how to call the stored procedure in Hibernate?